# Showing Derivative Definitions are Equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

**Definition 1:** Let $f:D→\mathbb R$ with $x_0$ an accumulation point of $D$ and $x_0\in D$. For each $x\in D$ with $x\neq x_0$, define

$$F(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$ The function $f$ is said to be *differentiable* at $x_0$ iff $F$ has a limit at $x_0$ and it's written as $\lim_{x→x_0}F(x)=f'(x_0)$. If $f$ is differentiable for all $x\in B\subset D$, we say $f$ is differentiable on $B$.

**Definition 2:** Let $f:D→\mathbb R$ with $x_0$ an accumulation point of $D$ and $x_0\in D$. For each $t\in \mathbb R$ such that $x_0+t\in D$ and $t\neq 0$, define

$$G(t)=\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{t}.$$

The function $f$ is said to be *differentiable* at $x_0$ iff $G$ has a limit at zero. If the limit exists, it is called the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$.

We are to show that these two definitions are equivalent, which I'm not exactly sure how you do that, but I think I have an idea. So I guess I would start by assuming that $f$ is the same function $f:D→\mathbb R$ and I would define the two functions $F(x)$ and $G(t)$ with $x_0\in D$ an accumulation point of $D$. So, we know there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $x_n\neq x_0$ that converges to $x_0$ and a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $t_n\neq t$ that converges to $t$. Starting with the second definition we know that $\{x_n+t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x_0+t$ and so $\{f(x_n+t_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f(x_0+t)$. Thus, we can write:

$$\{G(t_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty=\frac{\{f(x_n+t_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty-\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty}{\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$$ We know this converges to $G(t)$. From here, I'm not sure where to go or what to actually do. I think this is a step in the right direction but I couldn't be certain.

Comment: The graphs of $G$ and $F$ look the same, just that one is the horizontally-shifted graph of another: $G(t)=F(t+x_0)$. Can you deduce an equality between their limits from this?

Comment: The sequence $\{t_n\}$ should converge to $t=0$, then the sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n=x_0+t_n$ converges to $x_0$. Vice versa if $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$ the sequence $\{t_n\}$ where $t_n=x_n-x_0$ converges to $0$

Comment: @edm I like this and it completely makes sense. I guess I just have to try and think about what their limits would come out to be, or how $F(t+x_0)$ would come out to be the same limit. I guess part of my problem is not knowing the limits exist for certain.

Comment: $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}G(t)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}F(x)$ where lhs exists by second definition and the rhs exists by the first one , then identity is obvious.

Comment: @PeterMelech This is if I follow your statements about the sequences $\{t_n\}$ converging to $0$ and $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x_0+t$ is what we are using. It makes a bit of sense although I don't understand if $t\neq 0$ by definition then how can it converge to $t=0$

Comment: @help in the second definition it is said "iff G has a limit at zero"!

Comment: @help of course $G$ is not defined for $t=0$ but it can have a limit there, similarly $F$ is not defined for $x=x_0$ but it can have a limit there, and it has if and only if $G$ has a limit at $0$ and that is why both definitions are equivalent

Comment: @PeterMelech I think I get it now. That does make sense, although it's not defined it can still exist

Comment: @help What is defined is the limit, there exists a value $f'(x_0)$ so that whenever $x$ is close enough to $x_0$ the quotient $\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$ is close to $f'(x_0)$, equivalently if $t$ is close enough to $0$ the quotient $\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{t}$ is close to $f'(x_0)$